# OSX: Control where the red item count badge on NSCursor appears during drag

Tags: macos, cocoa, drag-and-drop, appkit, nscursor

My app, which accepts drags from other apps, has to choose its own cursors during a drag over its window.

For example, it has to be able to show the `dragLinkCursor` even if the user doesn't hold the option and cmd keys down, or show the `operationNotAllowedCursor` in some other cases.

This works nicely if the user drags single items. But ***if the user drags multiple items***, e.g. several files from **Finder**, the cursor also gets a red badge showing the number of items in it. And ***that red badge appears in the location where my chosen cursor is shown, overlapping it***. That's not good.

Apart from making my own cursor shapes that place their own badges in a different position, and me predicting where the OS drag handler will decide where to place the red badge depending on the pressed modifiers...

Is there a way to have the red badge appear in a specific location (e.g. always 20 px to the right so that it cannot overlap with the default cursors), or suppress it entirely, so that I could add my own when the mouse cursor is in my window?

Comment: Are you using custom cursors or do you set the cursor to the standard link cursors? The default link cursor and the red badge don't overlap. Can't you use the default link cursor?

Comment: I use custom designed cursors. And even if I did use the std ones: I don't only use the link cursor (which indeed cannot overlap as it doesn't use a badge) but others, too.

Comment: Can't you put the custom cursors in the same place as the default ones?